# how to read this function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def cat(xx):
    if (xx<1):
        return 5
    if (xx<2):
        return 2
    if(xx<3):
        return 4
    if(xx<4):
        return 7 
    if(xx<5):
        return 8
    if(xx<6):
        return 6
    if(xx<7):
        return 1
    if(xx<8):
        return 9
    if (xx<9):
        return 3
    else:
        return cat(xx-9)
print(cat(38))
```

the answer python gives me is 4. I am not sure why it gives me this number. I know there are multiple if statements and not elif but I don't know how that causes this answer

Comment: I suggest that you use a paper and pencil to trace the execution. What happens with the first call `cat(38)`? Which `return` statement is executed?

Comment: I'd suggest printing `xx` at the top of the `cat` function. That should give you a clue what's going on.

Comment: If you notice, this function calls itself in the final `else` statement. This is known as *recursion*. Since `cat(38)` leads to this recursive condition, the function is called with `cat(38-9)` or `cat(29)`. This process repeats itself until the argument passed to `cat` is less than 9.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does to the variable you're interested in.
If you're still confused, ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)

Comment: If it helps, you would get the same result with `else: return cat(xx % 9)`, with far fewer recursive calls.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it may help to suggest a Python debugger, such as `pdb`.

Comment: @h0r53 most python environments come with a debugger, so it is really up to OP to see "debugger" and find out what best fits their setup. That said, here's a handy list of python debuggers, but having sio many choices is usually not helpful for a beginner. https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools

Answer (score 3):

The stack call of `cat(38)` will be:

```
print(cat(38))
   return(cat(38-9))
       return(cat(29))
           return(cat(20))
               return(cat(11))
                   return(cat(2)) 
                       <-- will return 4 since `xx<3` will evaluate to true
```

Comment: so it continues to loop through the function since we returned the cat(xx-9) function

Answer (score 0):

The function keeps on substracting 9 to xx until it returns something different from `cat(xx-9)`. When you enter 38 you get 2 by the fourth time you enter the function recursively and then the output is 4

Answer (score -1):

```
else:
    return cat(xx-9)
```

So because you did `print(cat(38))` but there is no `if` statement when the number is above `9` so it will go to `else` but what you did was to recall the function instead of returning the number.

Why it gives you `4` every time is because the function is in a loop and it will continue to `xx-9` until it finds a valid if statement then it will return the number `4` for example:

`38 - 9 = 29, 29 - 9 = 20, 20 - 9 = 11, 11 - 9 = 2` <--- this is what the function is doing.

Solution:

```
else:
   return xx-9
```

Comment: The term *recursion* is more appropriate than *loop* here